# Forward of declarations not fixing incomplete type

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

Despite many questions similar to this I'm unable to find one that can answer such a simple query - however due to the volume you'll have to forgive me if I have missed it.

Within the following code, the following error is produced (using G++): `'error: field 'CompoundField' has incomplete type'`:

```
class SimpleClass;
class CompoundClass;

class CompoundClass{
    public:
    SimpleClass CompoundField;
};

class SimpleClass{
    public:
    unsigned int SimpleField;
};

int main(){
    CompoundClass obj;
    obj.CompoundField.SimpleField=5;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this when both classes have been forward-declared? A straight forward solution is to just move the `CompoundClass` to after the `SimpleClass`, or make `CompoundField` a pointer to `SimpleClass` but that doesn't help explain the underlying issue here.

To be more precise, other answers indicate this is due to the compiler not knowing the size of the *child* class (i.e. `SimpleClass`), why is this when the size of `SimpleClass` could be found with relative ease?

Comment: define 'relative ease'. C++ is still designed with the theoretical ability to write a single pass compiler. Waiting until `SimpleClass` is defined later would require potentially infinite lookahead. Consider the implications if the user defined `SimpleClass` after `main`.

Comment: @mythagel Define "single-pass." Definitions in a `class {}` scope for example are parsed first as declarations, then everything is parsed again with all the class member declarations visible. The problem here is that the type hierarchy of subobjects must be acyclic or you get objects of infinite size. Types forming a directed acyclic graph can be defined without forward declarations, which is the solution here. Forward declarations and incomplete types are only useful for defining references (including pointers and smart pointers).

Comment: @Potatoswatter Very good point, perhaps I should have said bounded lookahead instead. I was trying to get at the actual question, given that R4D4 seems to already be aware of the solution proposed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler sees this

```
class SimpleClass;
class CompoundClass;

class CompoundClass{
    public:
    SimpleClass CompoundField;
};
```

It needs to figure out how much memory a `CompoundClass` requires (has not got a clue about`SimpleClass` memory requirement).

As it does not know how many ints, strings etc.. to make space for - it throws its hands up.

But if you did

```
class SimpleClass;
class CompoundClass;

class CompoundClass{
    public:
    SimpleClass *CompoundField;
};
```

Then it would know - just need a pointer (`void *` will suffice for all eventualities!)